# Race condition stat and mkdir

Tags: c++, c, file, race-condition

I am working fixing on some coverity issues and i am confused about how to solve toctou for stat a directory and make a directory.

```
////////////////////////////////////
// Make sure storage dir exists. If
// not, create it.
if( stat( dir, &statBuff ) != -1 )
{
    if( S_ISDIR( statBuff.st_mode ) )
    {
        if( (dirPtr = opendir( fabcSsrDbStorageDir )) == NULL)
        {

        }
        closedir(dirPtr);
    }
}
else
{
    ////////////////////////////////////
    // dir directory
    // does not exist- create it
    // now.
    if( (mkdir( dir, S_IRWXU )) != 0 )
    {

    }
}
```

Please give your suggestions
Thanks

Comment: You tagged that with three programming languages but it doesn't even matter which one you use.

Comment: And one of these programming (the shell) has `mkdir -p` , which does exactly what you want.

Comment: @wildplasser Actually, `mkdir -p` doesn't do that without a race condition - it just tries to create the directory and treats a previous existence as a non-error.  There doesn't appear to be any equivalent to exclusive file creation with `open()` with `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` or `fopen()` with an `x` mode in any way under POSIX to create a directory.  Which honestly surprised me.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected. [I once implemented `mkdir -p` in C, but only in a single-process-setting] If you are the *sole* owner of the directories, there should be no problem, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `mkdir()`.  If the directory already exists, `EEXIST` will tell you.  Accept either zero or this return-code to indicate that you have, one way or the other, now accomplished your objective.  "Race conditions" cease to be an issue since `mkdir()` has taken care of that for you.

Comment: That would not be enough. File might exist, but be not a directory.

Comment: @SergeyA And a directory that ***didn't*** exist might be created in the meantime, as a ***file*** even.  So yes, the TOCTOU bug remains.

Comment: @AndrewHenle there is not enough context to be certain, but there are likely no real bugs in the code.

Comment: Thanks. Similarly how can we prevent race condition between stat a file and remove a file

Comment: @kumarRaja What's the point of checking if a file exists before trying to remove it?  Just remove it.  If it wasn't there `unlink()` will fail with `ENOENT`.

Comment: @SergeyA There doesn't appear to be a POSIX way to atomically create a directory with [`open( ..., O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_DIRECTORY | O_RDWR, 0755 );`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) where you could then use [`fdopendir()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopendir.html) on the file descriptor from `open()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have a condition that should happen only if the file is existed do some other logic and then remove file

Comment: @kumarRaja That's different - you're not checking if the file exists in order to remove it, you're using the state of the file existing to make a decision about what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the call to `stat`.

Call `opendir` to open the directory.  If it returns an error and `errno` is set to `ENOENT`, you know it doesn't exist at which point you call `mkdir`.

Comment: This solution would solve exactly nothing. The race is still there.

Comment: Actually, I think that it could be even further simplified:  just do `mkdir`.  If the directory already exists, you'll get `EEXIST`, and you can simply ignore it.

Comment: @rustyx How?  Instead of checking-then-using we're just using and verifying the return value.

Comment: There are two races in OP's code. `stat`-`opendir` and `stat`-`mkdir`.

Comment: @rustyx And by getting rid of `stat` both go away.

Comment: @rustyx I'd argue that `opendir` is the "use" case here in TOCTOU, and that `mkdir` is what you do when it fails.

Comment: Neither `stat` nor `opendir` write anything, I'd argue that that race is "benign". The one around `mkdir` is IMHO more severe. Anyway, the question is unclear (although it does mention "*toctou for stat a directory and make a directory*").

Comment: @rustyx I disagree with your first comment. That usage would remove the race. As for the second comment, I do agree that this is just a noise from coverity and should be just suppressed.

Comment: @dbush `opendir` returning `ENOENT` is the `TOC`. `mkdir` is the `TOU`. And in between, any number of processes could have A) created a link with that name B) created a file with that name, C) created a directory with that name, or D) changed the permissions of the parent directory to prevent you from even looking at the parent directory. So `opendir` returning `ENOENT` tells you absolutely nothing about whether that directory needs to be created, or can be created. In fact, calling `mkdir` after `opendir` fails is pretty much the canonical example of TOCTOU.

Comment: @user3386109 And there doesn't seem to be anything in POSIX that can do anything about it...

Comment: @user3386109 Seems appropriate to ask:  [**Is there a way on a POSIX system to atomically create a directory if it doesn't exist?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483396/is-there-a-way-on-a-posix-system-to-atomically-create-a-directory-if-it-doesnt)