# Is there a way on a POSIX system to atomically create a directory if it doesn't exist?

Tags: c, posix

Is there any way on a POSIX system to atomically create a directory only if it doesn't already exist?

Similar to

```
int fd = open( "/path/to/file", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, 0644 );
```

This doesn't work:

```
int dfd = open( "/path/to/dir", O_DIRECTORY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, 0755 );
```

fails on my Solaris 11 and Ubuntu 20.04 systems with `errno` set to `EINVAL` on Solaris and `ENOTDIR` on Ubuntu.

The [POSIX `open()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) states this for `O_CREAT`:

> If the file exists, this flag has no effect except as noted under `O_EXCL` below. Otherwise, if `O_DIRECTORY` is not set ...

Well, it's not a file, and `O_DIRECTORY` is set.

(Inspired by the question [**Race condition stat and mkdir**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482526/race-condition-stat-and-mkdir) - there doesn't appear to be any way in POSIX to atomically create a directory if it doesn't already exist.)

Comment: Something like `mkdir -p "/path/to/dir"`?

Comment: Why not [`mkdir()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir)?

Comment: Well, I'm tempted to write an answer with ust "No" with "I have read the whole POSIX standard", but that would be... exaggeration ;)

Comment: @BlockofDiamond `mkdir()` isn't guaranteed to create a *new* directory *and* atomically open it at the same time.  As far as I can tell, there's no way to do that under POSIX.  I don't know that there's a need for it similar to the security reasons that resulted in `O_EXCL` and the `"x"` exclusive mode that was added to `fopen()` in C11, but I did find it surprising that there's no way that I've been able to find to perform it.

Comment: @KamilCuk I suspect you're right - but just because I can't find something or figure out a way to do it doesn't mean someone else can't.  I did dig for a while - how do you think I know the `errno` values that result from trying?  :-)

Comment: If you're opposed to using `mkdir()` to create a directory you could try changing `O_RDWR` to `O_RDONLY` and see what happens.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I'm not opposed to using `mkdir()` as I see no benefit to using any capability to both create and open a new directory atomically.  But the linked question that inspired this question was written because of a Coverity check that flagged a race condition in how a new directory was being created, and I tried to solve all possible race conditions in the creation and subsequent use of that new directory and could not find a way to do so.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question in your title, mkdir does this -- there's no need for extra flags as mkdir will always "atomically" create a directory if and only if it does not exist (and the path is not a file).

From comments, it seems that you actually want to atomically create *and open* a directory, but it seems like this is an XY problem.  Why, as you cannot open a directory for write in any case?  If you first create and then open the directory (non-atomically) then there is no difference in behavior (and no race condition) as if in the interim, someone removed the directory, the open will fail.

If you're worried about only creating files in a directory with permissions set such that noone (else) can read them, you can check the permissions and ownership of the directory (with fstat) after opening it.

Comment: Because of `openat()` and relatives, having an fd for a directory does allow you to "write" it in some sense.  The race you might worry about is that you create the directory, then someone else removes it and creates a symlink with the same name pointing at some other directory, and then you open it.

Comment: If they can modify the containing directory, they could have done that before even the mkdir, and could modify the directory you created even with an atomic mkdir+open, so it is not clear what could be gained.

Comment: Suppose my adversary can write to `/foo/bar` but not to `/foo`.  If I had an atomic `mkopendir`, I could safely do `int d = mkopendir("/foo/bar/baz", 0700); int fd = openat(d, "/foo/bar/baz/important.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600);`.  If `/foo/bar/baz` is removed in between, `openat` will just fail. But if I do it with `mkdir / open / openat`, then in between `mkdir` and `open`, my adversary can `rmdir /foo/bar/baz ; ln -s /home/nate /foo/bar/baz` and I will overwrite `/home/nate/important.txt`.

Comment: *To answer the question in your title, mkdir does this...*  I'm not so sure.  Between the `mkdir()` call and any later call to something that uses that directory, such as `opendir()` or `chdir`, or even `open()` of a file in that directory, the original directory could be replaced with something else, such as a soft link to some other directory.  If you were able to use `open()` with `O_DIRECTORY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL` to create *and* open a directory in one atomic operation, that open descriptor could be used as a guaranteed reference to the directory that was created, with no race possible.

Comment: (cont)  I'm not convinced that there's any ***use*** for such a capability, but the ability do to that seems to be lacking.  And even if a legitimate use could be found that addresses some way to exploit that race condition, I suspect there would be other ways to prevent that attack vector from being usable.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge that race condition is no different from the adversary calling `rmdir` and `ln -s` _before_ you call `mkopendir()`. Perhaps something like `int d = mkopendir("/tmp/xx", 0700); int fd = openat(d, "/tmp/xx/important.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600); rename("/tmp/xx", "/foo/bar/baz");` can achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @root: I don't think so.  `mkdir("/foo/bar/baz")` will fail if `/foo/bar/baz` already exists as a symlink, and I"m supposing that `mkopendir` would do the same.